# Excel Macro Security Settings

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder if someone can help me. One of my clients is getting the following message when executing a specif macro with the shortcut Ctrl+Shft+C.

[image]

The macros are enabled and do run if you use the Macros tab under Developer to run them. However, if you try and use the shortcut key the message above appears.

If I change the shortcut to another letter (e.g. Ctrl+Shft+K) then the macro executes. Change back to Ctrl+Shft+C and the message appears again.

Client is running Office 2013 (latest build) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use ctrl+shift+c anyway because I use that all the time to paste with formatting...  As long as your macro line looks like this, it should work.

```
Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+C
```

If that doesn't work, I don't think it would actually be anything with the macro. I would start troubleshooting the OS and application.

1. Open powershell and run: (not strictly necessary if you are not on a domain machine, but it won't hurt anything)

   ```
   gpupdate /force
   ```
2. Run this command to set your update server to one that does win updates AND office application updates.

   ```
   Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false
   ```
3. Run windows update
4. Full shutdown, push button startup. See if the issue persists.
5. If that doesn't work, consider upgrading to newer version of Office.

This seems like pretty low prio for you, considering it does work with other keyboard shortcuts. I don't think it's an issue with Excel because it works intermittently.

Comment: Thanks. It has to be something with his machine. Will keep digging.